# Phonegap filetrasfer never returns success if the file is transfer

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

In my cordova(v 3.3) application i use file transfer plugins for transfering file from my device to server. 
code is like:

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
   ft.upload(filelocation, url,function onsuccess(response){
      alert("success");
      console.log("hi ");

   }, function(e){
       uploadFilesToServer(filelocation, url, options);//if fail again try to upload

   }, options);
```

The problem here is `onsuccess` method **never calls in samsung devices** but it **fires in nexus devices**. Really confusing.

**NOTE: But the file is transferred to server in both the devices**

Any help is much appreciable.